# REACT - How to display the text contained in an url

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native

The question is not as easy as it sounds, but I couldn't find a way to cover it fully without probably confusing the readers

I have a json message stored in an url, which has an url field itself.

So it would look something like this:

```
{ "type": "text", "url": "http://pastebin.com/raw/1U5vhVzH" }
```

Inside that url, there is the content I want to display, which is in this case, simple text

With my code, I can already obtain the pastebin url, but now I can't seem to find a way to display it's content.

If it was an image, it would be easy since I could use `<img src = {pastebinURL}` to get what's inside that json field url, How can I replicate the same behaviour for the text?

Here's my code so far (currently only printing the json field url):

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class App extends Component{
  constructor()
  {
    super();
    this.state={
      data: [],
    }
  }

  componentDidMount()
  {
    fetch('https://demo7443497.mockable.io/stream/text')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((findresponse)=>{
      console.log(findresponse.url)
      this.setState({
        data:findresponse.url,
      })
    })
  }

  render()
  {
    return(
        <div>

        <p> Below there should be some lorem ipsum text: </p>
        <p> {this.state.data} </p>



        </div> 
    )
  }

}

export default App;
```

Also if it is not asking too much, I attempted to display a video as well in the exact same way (this json url fiel contains a video instead of text) but for some reason It is only displaying a greyed out video with no content, like it wasn't recognizing the variable I am passing. Did I miss any obvious detail?

Here's my very similar code for displaying the video:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class App extends Component{
  constructor()
  {
    super();
    this.state={
      data: [],
    }
  }

  componentDidMount()
  {
    fetch('https://demo7443497.mockable.io/stream/video')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((findresponse)=>{
      console.log(findresponse.url)
      this.setState({
        data:findresponse.url,
      })
    })
  }

  render()
  {
    return(
        <div>


          <video width="400" controls>
          <source src={this.state.data} type="video/mp4" />

          </video>


        </div> 
    )
  }

}

export default App;
```

Comment: Did you know beforehand the resource type your second-url would have?

Comment: In this initial stage I do, but my next step will be precisely trying to detect which kind of data I have. But you can assume that I know it is plain text for now :)

Comment: you need to re-fetch the inner url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**text:**

```
import React, {
  Component
} from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: '',
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    fetch('https://demo7443497.mockable.io/stream/text')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {
        // now fetch the text
        fetch(response.url)
          .then(response2 => response2.text())
          .then(response2 => {
            this.setState({
              data: response2
            })
          })
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p> Below there should be some lorem ipsum text: </p>
        <p> {this.state.data} </p>
      </div> 
    )
  }
}
export default App;
```

**video:**

```
import React, {
  Component
} from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: ''
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://demo7443497.mockable.io/stream/video')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((findresponse) => {
        console.log(findresponse.url)
        this.setState({
          data: findresponse.url,
        })
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      {this.state.data
       ?
       <video width="400" controls>
        <source src={this.state.data} type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
      : null}          
      </div> 
     )
  }
}
export default App;
```

don't set your state to an array then cast it to string, make it an empty string on the start.
your video example is not working because on first render video is initialized with `this.state.data` which is an empty array, changing that to a string won't reinitialize video so you need that if statement there
hope it helps :D

Comment: Sir, the video code is working beautifully. About the text, I noticed with the help of Carloluis, that my text is not printing because http://pastebin.com/raw/1U5vhVzH is returning an empty String, maybe due to the first 2 empty lines in that sample text. If this is true, then I would love to understand how is the text being fetched. Why doesn't it fetch all the text in the url?

Comment: hmmm strange, if you run that fetch peace of code in the console of chrome(F12) on http://pastebin.com/raw/1U5vhVzH page, it will return the text, when i run it locally it returns empty string..
maybe some headers are missing that pastebin requires but the code, once you get past cors and some funky headers should work

Answer (score 0):

If it's a URL, then will re-fetching it works?

```
  componentDidMount()
  {
    fetch('https://demo7443497.mockable.io/stream/text')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((findresponse)=>{
      console.log(findresponse.url)
      fetch(findresponse.url)
        .then((urlResp) => urlResp.text())
        .then((response) => {
            this.setState({
              data:findresponse.url,
            });
          });
    });
  }
```

For the video, have tried opening the actual URL on a browser (i.e. Chrome) to check if it's a valid mp4, chrome should be able to easily read it.

Comment: The video does run perfectly if you go to the website, but when I try to fetch and display it using my react code, it doesn't run in Chrome or Mozilla (the only 2 browsers I tried). Could you see it running the code?

Comment: Have you checked chrome developer tools if there are any error? It might be CORS related error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-fetch your inner url in order to retrieve the text:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { data: '' }; // set data to string instead of an array
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://demo7443497.mockable.io/stream/text')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(findresponse => fetch(findresponse.url, { mode: 'no-cors' })) // re-fetch
      .then(textResp => textResp.text()) // assuming this is a text
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ data });
      });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p> Below there should be some lorem ipsum text: </p>
        <p> {this.state.data} </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

---

In other cases (images, video) should be the similar.
<s>Always need to re-fetch the inner url and decide how to process / display final data depending of the type (assuming you can always know)</s>

I just checked your *video* example and it is a simpler scenario, because `findresponse.url` (the initial response) has already the resource (image, video) and there is no need to re-fetch.
But, need to change your `state.data` initialization to an empty string instead of an array to prevent in the first render to initialize the video resource with an empty array. This also could be solved with a spinner.

Keep in mind whenever retrieving resources from server is important to display consistent data, consider a spinner while waiting for the image or video resource, etc.

You need to be careful with all the content you are retrieving, I assume probably you will fetch from another domain. Read about [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

---

Test case:

[image: Local test]

Comment: Sir, I'm afraid it is not showing me any output, did you try it out and it worked?

Comment: Yes, I ran this locally and we get nothing because the second response (`textResp.text()`) returns an empty string.

Comment: Oh, the url in the url json field (http://pastebin.com/raw/1U5vhVzH) does indeed have 2-3 empty lines of text so that's the reason indeed. 
So now, what I dont understand, is how the text is getting fetched in that pastebin url, is it only the first line? How can I manipulate the text I want to return?

Comment: @OhWords consider upvoting/select the helpful answers to your question in gratitude for the time and interest dedicated. Thanks

Comment: I did select an "accepted answer" and upvoted them, as I do not have 15 reputation yet my vote is "recorded but not publicly displayed".